# understanding the maximum number of threads running solr

Tags: tomcat, solr, lucene

I am running solr through tomcat on a Ubuntu machine with 16 cores. I observed that there are 30 threads alive. How do i know if i really need these many threads? and where to modify it to a small number? and is there a need for me to make modifications? I haven't found any info online about this. Thanks!

Comment: In what state all these 30 threads are? What do they do (you can observe that by sending `kill -3 pid`)? Unless they are not blocking on a monitor, I wouldn't consider this as a problem.

Comment: They are not blocking. In fact, it's automatically kicking off 30 threads even if no much traffic.

Comment: 30 threads waiting for work is not a performance concern. You don't really loss CPU, and you pay some memory for the stack of each thread. Don't loss sleep over it.

Comment: Gili, what do you suggest me to optimize? or just to monitor the memory usages would be good enough?